# Looking for a finite group satisfying certain properties

Tags: gr.group-theory, gt.geometric-topology, finite-groups

I would like to find examples of finite groups $G$ satisfying the following properties:

Let $F_2$ be the free group on two generators. There exists a positive integer $n\ne 1,2,4,8$ such that:

1. There is a surjective homomorphism $f : G\twoheadrightarrow(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^2$.
2. The induced surjection
   $$f_* : Surj(F_2,G)/\text{Inn}(G)\twoheadrightarrow Surj(F_2,(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^2)$$
   has all fibers of order $n^2$.
3. There is a subgroup $P\le\text{Out}(G)$ such that $P$ is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^2$ and acts freely and transitively on each fiber of $f_*$.
4. The action of $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})\subset\text{Out}(F_2)$ on $Surj(F_2,G)/\text{Inn}(G)$ is transitive.

I have basically no idea how one might come up with such a group. I believe any such group cannot be metabelian, though I don't have a proof.

Any ideas/suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you give an indication of why such a group is of interest to you?

Comment: @GeoffRobinson I believe a certain open subset of the Fermat curve $x^n + y^n = z^n$ can be realized as a moduli space for elliptic curves equipped with $G$-Galois covers (where $n,G$ are as in the question).